# Output to local file using cloud shell in vscode on a MAC

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-cloud-shell

I am new to VSCode on a Mac and I am using the Cloud Shell connected to Azure where I can run all my commands without issue. The problem I have is that if I want to use the export-csv command to export the information to a file I don't know how to point the output file to the Desktop of my Mac.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: you want to export the commands?

Comment: I added the solution below, please don't forget to mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using cloud shell all data is executed remotely on azure terminal so the cloud is saved to a blob storage, you can run export-csv command then download the data from the blob storage.

for more details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage
 [image]